# Finding a sequence of sets whose intersection is a null set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, rational-numbers

> Find a sequence of sets $I_n=\{r:r \in \mathbb{Q}, a_n\le r \le b_n\} $ in $\mathbb{Q}$, where $a_n, b_n \in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $$I_{n+1} \subset I_n\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}(b_n - a_n)= 0 $ but $$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n= \emptyset$$

Can anyone explain the question and how to go about its solution?

Comment: You should add a backslash "\" before the curly brackets in the definition of $I_n$ to make them visible :)

Comment: Furthermore, if the sets $I_n$ were defined as open intervals, you could take $a_n = 0$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. Now that the intervals $I_n$ are closed I suggest trying to imitate something similar. Make an educated guess and then try to prove that the intersection becomes zero.

Comment: The key here is to think... irrationally!

Comment: @hardmath why irrationally when both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are rationals?

Comment: It's worth comparing with the case of nested closed bounded intervals of real numbers, [Cantor's intersection theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem), where the intersection must be nonempty (a consequence of completeness).  Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the only possible loophole is for the corresponding point of nested intersection in the reals to be an irrational number.

Comment: Oh I get your point it's brilliant. This might be a stupid question but if Cantor's theorem applies to closed and bounded sets, how do we know that the sets in this sequence are closed and bounded?

Comment: Your sets are intervals of rational numbers that include the endpoints, $[a_n,b_n] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.  So you can think of getting this by intersecting the real interval (closed and bounded) with the subset of rationals, so in the subset topology these are still closed and bounded.

Answer (score 2):

consider a irrational number $i \in \mathbb{R}$...we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$....consider a incersing sequence of rationals converging to $i$ as {$a_n$} and consider a decreasing sequence {$b_n$} converging to $i$ and consider $J_n$= {$r \in \mathbb{R}| a_n \leq r \leq b_n$} then $J_n \cap \mathbb{Q} = I_n$ ...then by **cantor intersection property** $\bigcap_{n} J_n$ is singleton and contain $i$ only...so   $\bigcap_{n} I_n = \phi$

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense? Also does what you explained mean that $r$ is an irrational number by the squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Pick your favorite irrational number $\alpha$. Choose sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ of rational numbers such that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing, $a_n<\alpha$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\alpha$, $\{b_n\}$ is decreasing, $b_n>\alpha$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\alpha$.

For instance, if
$$
\alpha=\pi=3.141592\dots
$$
take $a_1=3$, $a_2=3.1$, $a_3=3.14$, $a_4=3.141$, $a_5=3.1415$, $a_6=3.14159$, and so on, 
and $b_1=4$, $b_2=3.2$, $b_3=3.15$, $b_4=3.142$, $b_5=3.1416$, $b_6=3.14160$, ...

Comment: I like this answer. Do you mind explaining how that is a such sequence?

Answer (score -1):

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take $a_n$ a rational number in the interval $ (\pi - \frac{1}{n}, \pi)$, and $b_n$ a rational number in $(\pi, \pi + \frac{1}{n})$. Now,
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n,b_n) = \lbrace \pi \rbrace.
$$
However, with your definition,
$$
I_n = (a_n,b_n) \cap\mathbb{Q},
$$
then
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n) \cap \mathbb{Q} = \lbrace \pi \rbrace \cap \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset.
$$
Remind that the set of rational numbers is not complete, but the set of real numbers is complete.

Comment: But $a_n,b_n\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ok, it's true, but you can take $a_n$ a rational number in $(\pi - \frac{1}{n},\pi)$, and $b_n$ a rational number in $(\pi,\pi + \frac{1}{n})$.